# Find the last index of a word(string) from a String(paragraph) in java

Tags: java, string

Find the last index of a word(string) from a String(paragraph) in java?

```
String sample="Give your club and/or district the publicity and recognition it deserves! Tell your local community about Toastmasters events, programs and member achievements. Use the news templates below to garner interest and awares are formatted and downloadable as Word documents.Click on a news release and save it to your computer. Localize the news release by replacing the bolded text with your club or district information. Proofread it for accuracy. "

String selectedText = tarea.getSelectedText(); // Select some text from the jTextpane then here -> selectedText = about
```

I need to find the last index of `selectedtext` not from the `Jtextpane`. I want to find the word(about) in the sample(String)

Comment: And what have you tried?.. A quick peek into apis of `String` would help

Comment: check lastindexof a sequence.

Comment: String selectedText = textpane.getSelectedText();
                        if (sample.contains(selectedText)) {
               lastindexof = sample.lastIndexOf(selectedText);
       }
But i need first index of the selectvalue from the String sample
also need to get the last index of the sample(String)

Comment: what is s here ? why don't you do it sample.lastIndexOf

Comment: sample is the string, it contains big paragraph, but i need to get the index value of the selectedtext.-> if the selectedText is contains in the sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`String::lastIndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) and [`String::contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

According [`JPane::getSelectedText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectedText())

> Returns the selected text contained in this TextComponent. If the selection is null or the document empty, returns null.

Check if there is text selected and sum to initial index the length of `selectedText` to get last char of last occurrence of.

```
String sample="Give your club and/or district the publicity and recognition it deserves! Tell your local community about Toastmasters events, programs and member achievements. Use the news templates below to garner interest and awares are formatted and downloadable as Word documents.Click on a news release and save it to your computer. Localize the news release by replacing the bolded text with your club or district information. Proofread it for accuracy."
String selectedText = tarea.getSelectedText();
int lastIndex = 0;
int firstIndex = 0;
if (!null.equals(sample) && sample.contains(selectedText)) {
    lastIndex = sample.lastIndexof(selectedText) + selectedText.length;
    firstIndex = sample.lastIndexof(selectedText);
}
```

Comment: i need to find the  start index of the SelectedText  from sample(String)

Comment: just delete this part: `+ selectedText.length`

Comment: spaces are also counted in the index  ah?

Comment: of course, space is a valid `char` in java, if you want to trim spaces use `sample.replace(" ", "");`